# Comparing a User Input to an already established table's column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, comparison

I have a User Input coming into the database to get compared to a table's column.  I've finding a ton of information on a column comparing another column, which didn't seem to work correctly.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE Procedure Check_Previous_Passwords
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier,
    @IncomingPassword varchar(25)
AS
    DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Passwords varchar(25))

    INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT *
    FROM User_Passwords
    WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk

    IF @IncomingPassword = @TempTable.Passwords
        --Then do stuff

GO
```

I'm pretty sure it's something I'm completely overlooking.  Thanks!

Comment: What is it you want to do if they are the same, or if they are different?

Comment: If they are the same, I have to create an error stating that they need a different password.  if they are different, then continue to the next function

Comment: but i'm throwing an error at the IF statement with the TempTable

Comment: You are trying to compare a varchar with a whole table of varchars. You probably want something like IF EXISTS (SELECT Passwords FROM @TempTable WHERE Passwords = @IncomingPassword)

Comment: Ahhhh!  gotcha! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE Procedure Check_Previous_Passwords
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier,
    @IncomingPassword varchar(25)
AS
    DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(25)

    SET @Temp = (SELECT TOP 1 Password 
                 FROM User_Passwords 
                 WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk 
                 ORDER BY someDate DESC)


    IF @IncomingPassword = @Temp
        BEGIN
              SELECT 'You can't reuse the same PW'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
              --do work
        END

GO
```

This just checks the last password to make sure that it's not the same. If you want to check the last N number of passwords we can use the IN clause or EXISTS

```
CREATE Procedure Check_Previous_Passwords
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier,
    @IncomingPassword varchar(25)
AS
    DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(25)

    SET @Temp = (SELECT TOP 1 Password 
                 FROM User_Passwords 
                 WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk 
                 ORDER BY someDate DESC)


    IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM User_Passwords up where up.ua_fk = @ua_pk and @IncomingPassword = up.Password))
        BEGIN
              SELECT 'You can't reuse the same PW'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
              --do work... like an insert
        END

GO
```

Comment: that's exactly what I need to do, IN clause because that table can vary in rows

Comment: then Gordon's answer should suffice. but i'll add the whole proc

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem @KevinFischer

Comment: It's stating I'm not returning anything.  I need it to return the bit true or false for more funtionality

Comment: I'm pretty sure I wasn't clear on that, so that's completely my fault.  I have functionality already in place for the "true / false" return.

Comment: @KevinFischer then just select 0 for the first IF and 1 for the else. Or use RETURN 1 and RETURN 0

Comment: I have this:          BEGIN
   SELECT -IsSamePassword = 1
        END
    ELSE
  BEGIN
   SELECT -IsSamePassword = 0
  END

my VB is stating that it's returning nothing

Comment: Two dashes are comments. Otherwise it will be Interpreted as a negative sign. If you remove that it shouldn't throw an error

Comment: i'm trying the RETURN idea.  I like that

Comment: i meant in SO, adding a @ wasn't allowed for some reason

Comment: @KevinFischer You have to encapsulate it in the code format for it not to think it's someone's username. Did you get it worked out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the SQL is good.  But when I call it in my VB, I'm getting "Expression does not produce a value"... aggravating.

Comment: I'm going to close this one and ask another.  seems like it's getting off subject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130236/discussion-between-scsimon-and-kevin-fischer).

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be passing passwords as clear text.

I also don't see why you are creating a temporary table.  You can simply do:

```
if (exists (select 1 from User_Passwords up where up.ua_fk = @ua_pk and @IncomingPassword = up.Password))
begin
. . .
end;
else
begin
. . .
end;
```

Comment: i don't really have much of an option on the passwords part.

Comment: so, i want to get this straight. everything after my AS should be removed and replaced with this, correct?

Comment: @KevinFischer . . . This would be the conditional logic in the stored procedure.