# Getting the return value from stored procedure and using it in program

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

This is a follow up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41049332/comparing-a-user-input-to-an-already-established-tables-column/41049491#41049491) where my stored procedure is this:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'Check_Previous_Passwords')
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping Procedure Check_Previous_Passwords'
    DROP  Procedure  Check_Previous_Passwords
END
GO

PRINT 'Creating Procedure Check_Previous_Passwords'
GO

CREATE Procedure Check_Previous_Passwords
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier,
    @IncomingPassword varchar(25)
AS
    DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(25)
    DECLARE @IsSamePassword bit

    SET @Temp = (SELECT TOP 1 up_Password 
                 FROM User_Passwords 
                 WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk 
                 ORDER BY up_PasswordDate DESC)


    IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM User_Passwords up 
                WHERE up.ua_fk = @ua_pk
                AND @IncomingPassword = up.up_Password))
        BEGIN
            SELECT @IsSamePassword = 1

        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @IsSamePassword = 0

        END
GO

GRANT EXEC ON Check_Previous_Passwords TO WEB

GO
```

I'm really sure that the SQL associated is returning a value. But when I'm bringing it into my VB.Net solution and using it, it's stating that my "Expression does not produce a value".  Well here's my VB code:

On button click:

```vb
If user_.Check_Previous_Passwords(user_) = True Then
    'throw error and set ResetPassword to true
End If
```

on the User.vb

```vb
Public Sub Check_Previous_Passwords(ByVal User As FoundationLibrary.User)
    Dim IsSamePassword_ As Integer
    Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand("Check_Previous_Passwords", DatabaseInterface_.Connection)
    objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ua_pk", ua_pk_)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncomingPassword", ua_Password_)
    DatabaseInterface_.Open()
    IsSamePassword_ = objCommand.ExecuteScalar
    DatabaseInterface_.Close()
    If IsSamePassword_ = 1 Then
        User.ua_ResetPassword_ = True
    Else
        User.ua_ResetPassword_ = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I have used `Dim IsSamePassword As Boolean`, then changing my `If` statement to equal `True`.  Still throwing the same error.

I have this feeling is really easy.

Comment: The stored procedure in your previous question is incomplete. In any case that sp returns a string not an integer or a boolean. Please show the actual code of the storedprocedure _Check_Previous_Passwords_

Comment: added the stored procedure

Comment: how is it incomplete?

Comment: In the previous question all the part relative to the -do stuff- was missing not here.

Comment: The method `Check_Previous_Passwords` needs to be a function if you want it to return a value. For the VB side of the problem, using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) will point out problems like that for you.

Comment: MSDN is extremely confusing to me.  I have no idea what Option Strict On actually does.

Comment: did some research on SO, looks like I should get into the habit of using Option Strict On every time I add functions to my solution.

Comment: question is, why you need procedure for this? Procedure is extra weight in maintenance.

Comment: That's what my boss asked for.  We're creating new functionality.  Create a passwords table that can vary in row size. if the company wants to compare passwords to x amount of previous passwords, find a way of doing so. throw errors when needed.  all of it was brand new except the current password (because, duh... have to login somehow, right!)

Comment: My point is (and this is just discussion) - although stored procedures live outside of compiled code (This is a PRO), it has many CONS. For example, your software is not DB Platform Agnostic, and if it is, you need to maintain 2+ procedures. While written in simple SQL, you can execute same code for SQL Server, Oracle, MySql. etc

Comment: i totally understand where you're coming from.  I had to write four different SPs because in the beginning there was also going to be a lockout/inactivity date based on company policy.  keep in mind, i have the SP code in both SQL server and in my solution as a script.

Comment: I'm all for discussion.  I'm still learning and trying to get my brain around these concepts.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL is more complicated than it needs to be - you could use

```
CREATE Procedure Check_Previous_Passwords
    @ua_pk uniqueidentifier,
    @IncomingPassword varchar(25)
AS
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM User_Passwords up 
    WHERE up.ua_fk = @ua_pk
        AND @IncomingPassword = up.up_Password
```

and the VB which uses it needs to be a function so that it can return a value:

```
Option Strict On
' ...'
Public Function Check_Previous_Passwords(ByVal User As FoundationLibrary.User) As Boolean
    Dim isSamePassword As Integer
    Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand("Check_Previous_Passwords", DatabaseInterface_.Connection)
    objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    objCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName"@ua_pk", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, .Value = ua_pk_})
    objCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@IncomingPassword", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, .Size = 25, .Value = ua_Password_})
    DatabaseInterface_.Open()
    isSamePassword = CInt(objCommand.ExecuteScalar)
    DatabaseInterface_.Close()

    User.ua_ResetPassword_ = (isSamePassword = 1)

    Return User.ua_ResetPassword_

End Function
```

I changed the `AddWithValue` parts to a version which works reliably. You should avoid `AddWithValue` - it will only bring you misery eventually: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Honestly, I was using some of the older code as a template (that's how they did it).

Comment: what will happen if isSamePassword = 0?  looks like it's always set to 1

Comment: The stored procedure counts how many records have `up.ua_fk = @ua_pk AND @IncomingPassword = up.up_Password` and returns that value. If it is zero, then `isSamePassword ` will be zero. The comparison `(isSamePassword = 1)` will then return `False`.

Comment: Ah!  so you're doing a true/false check inside the ()!  Gotcha!  I figured that would just create an error being that 0 !=1

Comment: @KevinFischer I wondered about coding it like that, but I decided that if I could give you something extra to find out about then it would be useful :) Some languages use `=` for assignment and `==` for comparison, which makes it a bit more obvious.

Comment: Sounds outstanding!  Thank you!  I'm a C# guy and the new job is VB and SQL so I can read it, but writing it correctly will take some practice.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Your stored procedure does not return any value. `SELECT @IsSamePassword = 0 statement only let the value`0 to `@IsSamePassword` variable. Write the `SELECT @IsSamePassword` statement to the end of your procedure or eliminate the `@IsSamePassword` variable.

```sql
CREATE Procedure Check_Previous_Passwords
@ua_pk uniqueidentifier,
@IncomingPassword varchar(25)
AS
DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @IsSamePassword bit

SET @Temp = (SELECT TOP 1 up_Password 
             FROM User_Passwords 
             WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk 
             ORDER BY up_PasswordDate DESC)


IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM User_Passwords up 
            WHERE up.ua_fk = @ua_pk
            AND @IncomingPassword = up.up_Password))
    BEGIN
        SELECT  1

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  0

    END
```

Or

```sql
CREATE Procedure Check_Previous_Passwords
@ua_pk uniqueidentifier,
@IncomingPassword varchar(25)  
AS
DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @IsSamePassword bit

SET @Temp = (SELECT TOP 1 up_Password 
             FROM User_Passwords 
             WHERE ua_fk = @ua_pk 
             ORDER BY up_PasswordDate DESC)


IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM User_Passwords up 
            WHERE up.ua_fk = @ua_pk
            AND @IncomingPassword = up.up_Password))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @IsSamePassword = 1

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @IsSamePassword = 0

    END

 SELECT @IsSamePassword
```

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean.

Comment: What do you see when you run the SP from SQL Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

This is just to show you more capability and techniques. In fact, you can really use `RETURN` in your SP

```sql
. . . . . 
IF EXISTS (SELECT ... )
    RETURN  1
ELSE
    RETURN  0
. . . . .
```

With that in place you will need to modify VB call to include a return parameter in the end, using parameter direction

```vb
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
```